# Is there an expression to describe "thin"?

Tags: expressions

Is there an expression in English for a thin old woman which corresponds to "Dry as a root" in French?

Comment: "Dry as a root" is English, not French. If there's a specific French phrase you're thinking of, I believe you're allowed to include it. However, there are some guidelines for translation questions you might want to look over. In particular, you should include more information about the meaning and context of the phrase. http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/translation/info

Comment: Do you want an idiom which describes her thinness ("stick-thin") or some other aspect?

Comment: Are you looking for something like *"thin as a rail"* or *"thin as a rake"*? Because we never use *dry* for *thin* in English the way the French seem to use *sèche*.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the word *withered*. [See Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=withered+old+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cwithered%20old%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwithered%20old%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwithered%20old%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwithered%20old%20face%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwithered%20old%20women%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwithered%20old%20age%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwithered%20old%20crone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwithered%20old%20men%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwithered%20old%20hand%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwithered%20old%20hag%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwithered%20old%20hands%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Collins on [sec comme un coup de trique](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/%C3%AAtre-sec-comme-un-coup-de-trique)

Answer (score 1):

We say "**withered**" to describe a thin, dried-out, elderly person - as in:

"*She's* a 'withered old bag/hag/nag/bird',"

-or-

"*He's* a 'withered old coot/codger'."

(If you're trying to be nice, substitute "***faded***" for "withered", and use  "flower" for a woman and "warrior" for a man.) (US)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't explicitly refer to an old woman, but people (including myself) will often use the phrase "as skinny as a rake".

> She's as skinny as a rake!

You could make reference to the woman's age if you wanted to by modifying the sentence to something like:

> That old bag's as skinny as a rake!

"Old bag" is a slang term (sometimes considered derogatory) for an old woman; usually one with a bad temper.

Comment: The previous answer's user handle give you the idea?!

Comment: Ha! I swear I didn't even notice that! An entertaining username nonetheless.

Comment: Just kidding. However, I don't think `skinny` is exclusive to old people

Comment: Thank you. I think in the context I need, "Skinny as a rake" is enough. I had read "Thin as a lath" somewhere once. Is that too old fashioned?

Comment: @Gerald To be honest, I have never heard of "thin as a lath".

Answer (score 0):

It's not an expression, but a single word. Still, I think you can try **[decrepit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/decrepit#decrepit__5)**

> 1.1 (Of a person) elderly and infirm:
>
> *a rather decrepit old woman*

[Oxford]